# Office web add-in : Office.initialize() function

Tags: ms-office, outlook-web-addins

I am struggling to understand, and don't find an example to exactly match what I am trying to achieve. Which is to have an MS Outlook ribbon bar icon, which when clicked displays a Dialogue Box. I played about with a demo, threw out superfluous functionality and got a Hello World going - but it is JQuery and I want to use to use AngularJs, to reuse much of an existing app.

Firstly, the example manifests all seem to have something like

```
    <DesktopFormFactor>
      <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
```

This seems to be for functions which are invoked when the user clicks an icon on the ribbon bar. Would I be correct to assume that I don't need that, if I just use a `<script src=>` tag to include an such files of functions?

My app will have only a single view, so whereas in the demo all `*.js` files have something like

```
// The Office initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
```

Would I be correct to assume that I need only have such  call one, in the controller of my sole view?

Sorry if this seems pretty basic stuff, but all of the demos & docs seem to be close to what I want, but not exactly. Happy holidays!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Use of FunctionFile***

FunctionFile specifies the source code file for operations that an add-in exposes through add-in commands(Ribbon buttons) that execute a JavaScript function instead of displaying UI.
Add-ins can decide either to display some UI in task pane or execute a javascript function in background. For [UI-less add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook), you will have to specify a FunctionFile.

In your case, `FunctionFile` can be ignored.

***Use of Office.initialize***

Office Add-ins include the Office.js library and the library expects your start-up code not to call any APIs until the library is fully loaded. There are two ways that your code can ensure that the library is loaded.

1. Use [Office.initialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office#initialize-with-officeinitialize): An initialize event fires when the Office.js library is fully loaded and ready for user interaction. You can assign a handler to it.
2. Use [Office.onReady](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office#initialize-with-officeonready): Office.onReady() is an asynchronous method that returns a Promise object while it checks to see if the Office.js library is fully loaded.

Examples:

```
Office.initialize = function () {
    // Office is ready
};
```

Or

```
Office.onReady(function(info) {
    if (info.host === Office.HostType.Outlook) {
        // Based on host, decide what to display.
    }
    if (info.platform === Office.PlatformType.PC) {
        // Make minor UI changes, if required.
    }
});
```

In your case, you can use initialize/onReady once.

Comment: An excellent and informative answer. Thank you very, very much

Comment: Thank again for your help. Now I hit another problem. Could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53946813/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-the-target-origin-provided-htt Thanks